# Find positive numbers from file using python

Tags: python

I have a file containing a number of columns having some numerical values. Using python, how would I print summary information for the positive numbers from a particular column?

Example:

```
0
0
1
0
0
0
```

For the above input, I'd like the output to be:

```
number of positive numbers:  1
sum of the positive numbers: 1
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have already attempted please?

Comment: No idea how should I try it...May be you could suggest me some way

Comment: @user2525107 You can't have no idea. You must have some learning materials available to you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `re` module. `r'^\d+$'` would match the lines only if it contain positive integer numbers.

```
>>> s = '''0
0
1
0
0
0'''.splitlines()
>>> import re
>>> sum([int(i) for i in s if re.search(r'^\d+$', i.strip())])
1
```